# Resolve promise inside chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm having some trouble resolving promises inside a chain. In the JSBin below you can see the code I have (NodeJS and mongo). How can I return the data from 2 levels down the chain? Here is the code and JSBIN

```
function test(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  return scrapeIt({
    url: url,
    headers: { 'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36' }
  }, {
      urls: {
        listItem: '#list',
        data: {
          url: {
            selector: "span[data-label='url']"
          }
        }
      },
      currentPage: {
        selector: 'span.current',
        convert: x => parseInt(x)
      },
      pages: {
        selector: 'span.pages',
        convert: x => parseInt(x)
      }
    }).then(({ data, response }) => {
      return MongoClient.connect(config.db.serverUrl, function (err, db) {
        var dbo = db.db(config.db.name)
        var urlsToInsert = data.urls

        return dbo.collection(config.db.collection).find({ 'url': { '$in': data.urls } }, { projection: { _id: 0 } }).toArray(function (err, res) {
          if (res && res.length > 0) {
            // Exclude properties already in DB
            urlsToInsert = urlsToInsert.filter(x => !res.some(y => x.url == y.url))
            if (urlsToInsert && urlsToInsert.length > 0)
              return dbo.collection(config.db.collection).insertMany(urlsToInsert, function (err, res) {
                console.log("Number of documents inserted: " + res.insertedCount)

                db.close()
                return urlsToInsert
              })
          }
        })
      })
    })
})
}

test('https://www.google.com').then(({ data, response }) => {
  console.log(data)
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
})
```

[JSBin snippet](https://jsbin.com/cejuruxofu/edit?js)

## Update 1

My actual code is much longer so I took out a lot of the code that was not required for the issue to make sense. I fixed the issue with the urlsToInsert being null. Also returning now urlsToInsert.

Comment: You have `var urlsToInsert = []` (empty Array) and `urlsToInsert = urlsToInsert.filter(...)` (still empty Array), so the test `(urlsToInsert && urlsToInsert.length > 0)` is bound to be falsy, is it not? Where is `urlsToInsert` supposed to be populated?

Comment: I fixed the issue on my question about `urlsToInsert`, basically just change `var urlsToInsert = data.urls`. Thanks for observation @Roamer-1888

Comment: As far as I can tell, of the methods you use here, only `MongoClient.connect()` accepts a nodeback (therefore needs to be promisified).
Other methods return values :
 - `collection.find().toArray()` returns `Array`
 - `.insertMany()` returns `document`

If you know otherwise, could you please post links to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to rewrite the last part but your code would not work because you're setting `urlsToInsert` to an empty array and then filtering it.

You're returning `propertiesToInsert` that's never defined anywhere in your code.

```
.then(
  ({ data, response }) =>
    new Promise(
      (resolve,reject)=>
        MongoClient.connect(config.db.serverUrl,(err, db) =>
          (err, db) =>
            (err)
              ? reject(err)
              : resolve(db.db(config.db.name))
        )
    )
).then(
  dbo=>
    new Promise(
      (resolve,reject)=>
        dbo.collection(config.db.collection).find(
          { 'url': { '$in': data.urls } },
          { projection: { _id: 0 } }
        ).toArray((err, res) =>
          (err)
            ? reject(err)
            : resolve(res)
        )
    ).then(
      res=>{
        var urlsToInsert = [];
        if (res && res.length > 0) {
          // Exclude properties already in DB THIS MAKES NO SENSE, FILTERING AN EMPTY ARRAY
          urlsToInsert = urlsToInsert.filter(x => !res.some(y => x.url == y.url))
          if (urlsToInsert && urlsToInsert.length > 0) {
            return new Promise(
              (resolve,reject)=>
                dbo.collection(config.db.collection).insertMany(urlsToInsert, function (err, res) {
                  if(err){reject(err);}//this never happens anyway
                  console.log("Number of documents inserted: " + res.insertedCount);    
                  db.close();
                  //what are you returning here?
                  resolve(propertiesToInsert)
                })
            )
          } 
          return [];//what to return if there are no urls to insert (always because you're filtering empty array)
        }
      }
    )
)
```

Comment: I fixed the issue on my question about `urlsToInsert` and `propertiesToInsert`. Basically just change `var urlsToInsert = data.urls` and `resolve(urlsToInsert)`. Have a doubt on your answer, on the last then I see it still uses dbo but is not passed down the chain... would it still have access to it?

Comment: @vcliment89 Corect, I updated the answer so the promises are nested differently to have dbo in scope.

Comment: Looks like when the last promise is resolved I'm not able to read the data here

`test('https://www.google.com').then(({ data, response }) => {
  console.log(data)
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
})`